# Symmetrize not duplicating properly

Tags: rigging

When I try to symmetrize one bone structure for a model I'm working on it instead rotates it 90 degrees and keeps it on the same side of the model. I have the bones renamed to the .L But I bet there is some simple error I have causing issues for it.
[image: When]

[image]

Comment: Inverted left and right? Left is for the left of the model not the left of the screen

Comment: by default Blender will symmetrize on the object X axis, so may need to rotate it in Edit mode on the Z axis, or choose another axis on the Operator box

Answer (score 0):

By default Blender will symmetrize on the armature's X axis, your armature is currently oriented along the Y axis, so you can either rotate it in *Edit* mode on the Z axis so that it's correctly oriented along the X axis, or, once you've symmetrized, choose another axis on the *Operator* box.